# how to access a function defined in app_controller from a ctp

Tags: cakephp

I have function in app_controller.php.The function is like:

```
    function globalSum($Var1,$Var2)
    {
        $Var3 = $Var1 + $Var2;
        return $Var3;
    }
```

Now I want to access this function from any CTP file to get the value after sum.when I call this function the arments will be send from the ctp file.
So,anybody can tell me how to call this function with arguments from the ctp file??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

The way you're trying to do this probably isn't the best, seeing as it's working against the MVC architecture that CakePHP uses.

In MVC, the ctp file is your view and should only act as a template, to the greatest extent possible, with any values that you need in the view should be passed to it from the controller.

You have a number of simple solutions to your problem.

One is simply to do the addition in the view:

index.ctp

```
<?php
echo $var1 + $var2
?>
```

For such a simple operation, why bother with a separate function?

If your function is more complicated, you can put it in the AppController and then set the view variable in the controller that the action belongs to. For example:

app_controller.php

```
<?php
function globalSum($Var1,$Var2) {
    $Var3 = $Var1 + $Var2;
    return $Var3;
}
?>
```

posts_controller.php

```
<?php
function index() {
    $this->set('var3', $this->globalSum($var1,$var2));
}
?>
```

index.ctp

```
<?php
echo $var3;
?>
```

Hope that helps.